# While connecting to mysql showing socket error

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I have mysql server installed and it contains data also. I was trying to connect to mysql from ruby code. For that purpose I installed mysql gem using `gem install mysql`. The connection part in my program is giving below

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
require 'csv'
$user_name = "root"
$pas_wrd = "password"
def mysql_connect(db_name)
begin
  db = Mysql.real_connect("localhost", "#{$user_name}", "#{$pas_wrd}", "#{db_name}")
  return db
rescue Mysql::Error => e
  puts "Error code: #{e.errno}"
  puts "Error message: #{e.error}"
  puts "Error SQLSTATE: #{e.sqlstate}" if e.respond_to?("sqlstate")
end
end
```

It was written some day before and done the job. But when I try to use the same code It shows a mysql gem error,something like 'initialize' not found. By searching I found a solution like re-installing the gem. for re-installing I user the command `rvmsudo gem install mysql`. The above problem was solved. But it showing another error like

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I tried manually using `mysql -u root -p`

it is also showing the same error.

My mysql `my.cnf` content is given below.

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
tmpdir          = /home/presoft/Documents
skip-external-locking
```

The mysql is not running in my system.

```
ps aux | grep mysql
presoft   3823  0.0  0.0   4368   816 pts/0    S+   10:41   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I tried to start using using `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` which gave the result of

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
start: Job failed to start
```

Can any one help me to find a solution because db containing large amount of valuable data.

Thanks

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`service mysql start`

This will start mysql service. newer linux machine consider mysql as service

Comment: Showing an output given below                                          ** start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.76" (uid=1000 pid=3962 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")**

Comment: try with sudo service mysql restart

Comment: start: Job failed to start

Comment: may be need to reinstall the mysql. try at your own risk sudo apt-get remove mysql-common mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-common mysql-server

Comment: Ok,But the data will loose isn't it.                                  Thanks for the quick replay.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24490/discussion-between-babasaheb-gosavi-and-menon)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem from the above answer tip. The problem was my mysql server was corrupted.

So I first run the command

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-common mysql-server
```

It will remove the all mysql files and configurations with out deleting the data. After running please carefully watch the process and do the need full  any warning or error come.
I got a warning like

```
dpkg: warning: while removing mysql-common, directory '/etc/mysql' not empty so not removed.
```

So I removed the file and re run the above command. After the successful execution. I re-installed the mysql using

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-common mysql-server
```

then set the root password. After getting in to server The data is safe.